# How to fetch price for all suppliers in joined table

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT
    price
FROM prices
left join suppliers s on prices.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
AND prices.id_product = 57;
```

Table structures are as follows:

Suppliers:

| id_supplier | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier 1 |
| 2 | Supplier 2 |
| 3 | Supplier 3 |

Prices

| id_pk | id_product | date | price | id_supplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 57 | 2022-12-29 | 4.99 | 1 |
| 2 | 57 | 2022-12-29 | 6.99 | 2 |

So based on the data above, I wish to create a query which fetches all prices for all supplier for a given product, even for Supplier 3 (which we do not have a price for in which case it should return 0)

Outpout I require is as follows:

| id_supplier | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.99 |
| 2 | 6.99 |
| 3 | 0 |

Is this possible?

Comment: Your description makes sense for an *inner* join but your query shows an *outer* join, so you're returning ALL prices and any matching suppliers for product 57.  Should you be joining the tables in the reverse order? Some sample data would probably help here.

Comment: You need to use a right join with a CASE statement, since you said you want all suppliers.

Comment: @Stu, I have added some sample data which I hope illustrates my problem better

Comment: Please edit your data, as per the example I gave for you. Then, please add the exact and complete results you want for that input. (You probably also have a products table, which should also be included.)

Comment: @MatBailie The products table can be ignored, I only need the supplier ID and price.  I have added the output table I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the tables joined in the wrong order.

You want all rows from supplier, so that's the LEFT table.

```
SELECT
  s.*,
  COALESCE(p.price, 0)
FROM
  suppliers   s
LEFT JOIN
  prices      p
    ON  p.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
    AND p.id_product  = 57
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN price = 57 THEN 57 
      WHEN s.id_supplier IS NULL THEN 0 
      END AS price 
FROM prices
LEFT JOIN suppliers s on prices.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
```

If I am understanding your problem correctly then this should work. Using case statement will get you price as 57 when price is 57 and when id_supplier IS NULL it will assign 0 to that row. Let me know if this helps.

Edit:

```
SELECT 
      s.id_supplier,
      CASE WHEN price = 57 THEN 57 
      WHEN price IS NULL THEN 0 
      END AS price
FROM prices
RIGHT JOIN suppliers s on prices.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
```

This query will select all the suppliers where price is either 57 or null.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me.  I have added the output table I need to my question to demonstrate what I am after

Comment: I get it now, I think. You want all suppliers id in your output so you have to include the complete suppliers table in the query. You can do that by either using a RIGHT JOIN in the query I wrote above or switch tables names. There will be 1 more change so I will just edit my answer with new query.